# Trouble with retrieving 'ISO-8859-5'-encoded string from file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

In my project I'm using third-party library which reads DICOM file and displays some data from it. When it comes to read properties with cyrillic symbols, I get broken string as output. By using encoding/decoding tool I determined that cyrillic symbols were encoded with ISO-8859-5 and then dispalyed as ISO-8859-1.

[image]

So my specific question: having a string variable with value:

> Á°ÀÁµ¼±°µ²°

how can I convert it to:

> САРСЕМБАЕВА

by using JavaScript?

Comment: Nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=DICOM+convert+to+utf8

Comment: @mplungjan Converting .dcm file is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [library](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-codepage) which allows to solve the problem like:

```
var repairedString 
        = cptable.utils.decode(28595, brokenString);
```